# How to play tapped List Item Song

Tags: android, android-listview, mp3, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I am using listview and at the bottom of the screen using media controllers, for the first when i do tap on any of the list item, that time i am able to play that song, but after that when i do tap on another list item, its not playing that music (my mean not stopping existing when and not starting new one)

```
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            strTitle = actorsList.get(position).getTitle().toString();
            textAudioTitle.setText(strTitle);
            strURL = actorsList.get(position).getUrl().toString();
        }
    });


     public void play(){           
       mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strURL);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
      finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
      startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
         oneTimeOnly = 1;
      } 

      endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d : %d", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
      );
      startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d : %d", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
      );
      seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
      myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);

      btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

   private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d : %d", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
   public void pause(){       
      mediaPlayer.pause();
      btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the media if it's playing on `ItemClick`

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            strTitle = actorsList.get(position).getTitle().toString();
            textAudioTitle.setText(strTitle);
            strURL = actorsList.get(position).getUrl().toString();

            if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are never calling the mediaPlayer.stop() for the current song being played.

Comment: so how can i do control on that to play new song ?

Comment: Stop the media player from playing the song being currently played using some event handler and then start playing the new song.